# Help for literature school work

Tags: single-word-requests, present-tense

One word to describe someone who is secretive or shy, possibly doesn't like to be around people and old??

I have been asked to describe this lady in one word but this is what I have come up with just was wondering if anyone knew a single word what maybe meant all of these as I've been restricted to one word. If no single words a more simple way to say it please.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. To better understand your request, please include some more background. Why must it be a single word? What is wrong with *secretive* or *shy*? How would you use it in a sentence? I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Is "old" an important component in the word choice?

Comment: Who is asking you to come up with one word for this lady?  If there is one word for secretive or shy, possibly doesn't like to be around people and old" then there must be another word for ".......and young" and yet another for ".....and middle aged".  You are asking one word to do too much work!  Forgetting about the age factor, "withdrawn" is a possibility.  She is a withdrawn, elderly lady who likes to keep to herself

Comment: For "secretive and shy," the word _reclusive_ ("marked by withdrawal from society: SOLITARY," according to Merriam-Webster) works; but it doesn't say anything about the age of the person so described.

Answer (score 1):

How about *[reticent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reticent)*?

Other possibilities (synonyms) might be reserved, withdrawn, introverted, inhibited, or diffident.  Check your dictionary for the one which seems closer.  Also consult Roget's Thesaurus.